# Is there a way to force a context to complete the SaveChanges during SaveChanges event?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, events

So what I am trying to do is an event source which listens on a given context for the SaveChanges event and then gets all the changed entries and pushes out the changed properties of those entries.

E.g.

```
public class ContextChangeListener {
    public event EventHandler<ContextChangeEvent> ContextChanges;

    private ObjectContext _context;

    public ContextChangeListener(ObjectContext context) {
        _context = context;
        _context.SavingChanges += OnSavingChanges;
    }

    protected virtual void OnSavingChanges(object source, EventArgs evt) {
        var handler = ContextChanges;

        if (handler == null) {
            return;
        }

        var changedEntries = 
            _context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(
                EntityState.Added | EntityState.Deleted | EntityState.Modified);

        foreach (var changedEntry in changedEntries) {
            handler.Invoke(this, new ContextChangeEvent(changedEntry));
        }
    }
}
```

What I wonder now is, say that I get entries which have the state Added. There may be the case where their PK hasn't been generated yet. Is it possible to listen for an event which is sent AFTER the changes has been saved.

1. SavingChanges event occurs; add all the changed entries to a collection and wait for "ChangesCommited" event.
2. "ChangesCommited" event occurs; send out ContextChangeEvent.

If this isn't possible, then is it possible to force EF to commit the changes from the OnSavingChanges method?

Answer (score 1):

You could inherit from ObjectContext and implement IObjectContext then wrap the SaveChanges method:

```
public class MyContext : ObjectContext, IObjectContext
    {
        public event EventHandler ContextSaved;

        public void SaveChanges()
        {
            base.SaveChanges();
            if (ContextSaved != null)
                ContextSaved.Invoke(this, null);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            base.Dispose();
        }

        public IRepository<T> GetRepository<T>() where T : class
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```